# Is there an opposite of .cloneNode?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am writing a recipe website submit form and in the form I increase the amount of ingredients with this code.

```
addIngredientsBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let newIngredients = ingredientDiv.cloneNode(true);
    let input = newIngredients.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    input.value = '';
    ingredientList.appendChild(newIngredients);
});
```

how do I reverse this to remove nodes from the form?
Thanks for any help

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: IMO, deletion is not the opposite of cloning a node. But no matter. What you can do is do `node.parentNode.removeChild(node);`

Comment: @E.Maggini The only thing I tried is changing clone node to false and I was able to create a new button but that obviously didn't work

Comment: @ControlAltDel would i put node.parentNode.removeChild(node); after ingredientsList or on the newIngredients line?

Comment: You wouldn't put it in this code at all. You should have a delete button somewhere, and the event listener for that should delete the node that you want to remove.

Comment: You can also use `node.remove()`. This is equivalent to `node.parentElement.removeChild(node)`

Comment: @Barmar im being really dumb but I can't get it to work, do you  mean like this? ```removeIngredientsBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let oldIngredients = ingredeintDiv.nodeName.remove();
});```

Comment: `function() {let divToRemove = <code that selects the appropriate div>; divToRemove.remove(); }`. Filling in that missing code is an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you add each node you can do something like this:

```
newIngredients.addEventListener('click', function(){
   this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
});
```